# "ErrorTypeError: Cannot read property 'alg' of undefined" JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I'm following a tutorial: https://github.com/eXtremeXR/APIAuthenticationWithNode/tree/Part_%2312

And during the sign-up local part, there was an error

> Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated.

But I managed to solved that by using **try-catch** blocks. But again due to the main error:

**`TypeError: Cannot read property 'alg' of undefined`**

Every request I make returns me an error even though the registration is really successful.

The error points me to this block:

```
signToken = user => {
  return JWT.sign({
    iss: 'CodeWorkr',
    sub: user.id,
    iat: new Date().getTime(), // current time
    exp: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1) // current time + 1 day ahead
  }, JWT_SECRET);
}
```

What's the cause of this and how do I solve it?

---

Here's the full controller code:

```
const JWT = require('jws');
const User = require('../models/user');
const { JWT_SECRET } = require('../configuration');

signToken = user => {
  return JWT.sign({
    iss: 'CodeWorkr',
    sub: user.id,
    iat: new Date().getTime(), // current time
    exp: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1) // current time + 1 day ahead
  }, JWT_SECRET);
}

module.exports = {
  signUp: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const { email, password } = req.body;

      // Check if there is a user with the same email
      const foundUser = await User.findOne({ "local.email": email });
      if (foundUser) { 
        return res.status(403).json({ error: 'Email is already in use'});
      }

      // Create a new user
      const newUser = new User({ 
        method: 'local',
        local: {
          email: email, 
          password: password
        }
      });

      await newUser.save();

      // Generate the token
      const token = signToken(newUser);
      // Respond with token
      res.status(200).json({ token });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "Error" + err
      })
    }
  },

  signIn: async (req, res, next) => {
    // Generate token
    const token = signToken(req.user);
    res.status(200).json({ token });
  },

  googleOAuth: async (req, res, next) => {
    // Generate token
    const token = signToken(req.user);
    res.status(200).json({ token });
  },

  facebookOAuth: async (req, res, next) => {
    // Generate token
    const token = signToken(req.user);
    res.status(200).json({ token });
  },

  secret: async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('I managed to get here!');
    res.json({ secret: "resource" });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I got the answer. I'm wondering how is it my tags in this question draw much fewer SO users. It seems to me that you can get answers faster when you're in the mobile development tags.

The answer is the project is somehow requiring wrong library? In the sample project, it has:

```
const JWT = require('jws');
```

But after looking at some more JWT sample projects, I realized it should be:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
```

solved!